# Unable to write > 1200 files to Google App Engine Java with GCS in development server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, development-environment, google-cloud-storage

Writing files to google cloud storage in production environment of GAE runs fine. 
But when I try to import my productive data (6-7GB) into the development server I always got errors, when I try to write more than ~1200 files. The first 1200 files work fine, but then I always got exceptions. In that case I need to delete some files, and afterwards I can successfully write other files to GCS.

My Testenvironment is:

- appengine-gcs-client 0.4.2.
- appengine-java-sdk-1.9.13
- Win 7 Prof (x64), NTFS, Eclipse Kepler

And here is the code I use:

```
byte[] content = ..
GcsFilename fn = new GcsFilename("cms-gi-pdf", "zip-dwdwos--Nwrg1aTk7DSRn9gAWnT");
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("binary/octet-stream").acl("project-private").build();
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fn, options);
outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content));
outputChannel.close();
```

The exception happens on the last line (close()). Here is the stacktrace:

> 15:43:40 WARNING
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.FileMetadata:setFinalized:Caught
>   IOException while attempting to write blob 15:43:40 INFO
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper:doRetry:RetryHelper(11,88
>   ms, 1 attempts,
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@6abbeea):
>   Attempt #1 failed [java.io.IOException], sleeping for 281 ms
>
> ...
>
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   RetryHelper(8,866 s, 6 attempts,
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@6abbeea):
>   Too many failures, giving up  at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:127)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl.close(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:198)
>     at
>   de.daysout.generic.filesystem.gcs.GoogleCloudStorage.write(GoogleCloudStorage.java:45)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: com.google.appengine.api.files.FinalizationException
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:617)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:594)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.open(FileServiceImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openForAppend(FileServiceImpl.java:471)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openForAppend(FileServiceImpl.java:190)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.openWriteChannel(FileServiceImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.append(LocalRawGcsService.java:181)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.finishObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:245)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1.call(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:201)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1.call(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:198)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
>
> ...  72 more Caused by:
>
> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException:
>   ApplicationError: 101:
>   /gs/writable:oOUcuZuodalavuikpIHUFA?name=cms-gi-pdf%2Fzip-dwdwos--Nwrg1aTk7DSRn9gAWnT
>   is already finalized  at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.throwError(LocalFileService.java:201)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.files.dev.LocalFileService.open(LocalFileService.java:299)
>   ...

This is reproducable. Until yesterday I used appengine-gcs-client 0.2. But I had the same problem with that version. This is annoying as I am not able to test my software with production data.

And here are my questions:

- Is this an error or are there any limitations in the devlopment server?
- Has someone used appengine-gcs-client in dev server with more than 1200 files?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a natural limit of "GCS" on the devserver. As you can see, your error during `.close()` comes from attempting to finalize the writes. The finalize writes code is seeing IOExceptions happening due to the failure to write past the limit, and is thus attempting to retry the write. Naively, it doesn't know *why* the IOException occurred, and just retries as if the disk was failing or busy. Could you tell me if you've specified a storage location when launching devserver, or whether your disk is full?

It really comes down to the fact that devserver is not production. You can do a lot of things, but dealing with 7GB of "GCS" in thousands of objects is not one of them, apparently. I'd suggest writing tests that don't need to use that much data if you intend to run them on local. You should be testing on small, well-chosen cases, and trusting the platform to perform at scale when you actually push many more objects. You can always write integrity tests to run on your production data, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use a 732GB almost empty NTFS partition. And I use the default eclipse settings when starting devserver (-war D:\myproject). Currently I am using only a subset of my database on devserver. Unfortunately that means that I can't test some daily running administrative jobs (which work on the complete dataset only). So I can identify some problems only, when they occur on the productive system.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the backing "GCS" store to devserver is not able to handle such large sizes, despite the disk having space left. 

Could you try to use the latest SDK? (1.9.17)

Finally, I'd advise that if you have a complex piece of code that can't be decomposed into smaller unit-testable functions, that you implement an integrity check test that uses the entire function, and run that at regular intervals on production if you truly want to ensure that it works properly. It shouldn't break any quotas to just run this once a week or after major changes.

Comment: Also, the GCS client for java is now in version 0.6, so perhaps upgrading from 0.2 will help.